# Why does COALESCE fail when I add a MAX to the argument?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'll make this as simple as I can (tall order for me, according to every presentation course I've taken).

```sql
SELECT '2021-03-23 14:30:56.541 +0000'::TIMESTAMP;                      -- Works
SELECT MAX('2021-03-23 14:30:56.541 +0000'::TIMESTAMP);                 -- Works (obv.)
SELECT COALESCE('2021-03-23 14:30:56.541 +0000'::TIMESTAMP, '');        -- Works
SELECT COALESCE(MAX('2021-03-23 14:30:56.541 +0000'::TIMESTAMP), '');   -- Timestamp '' is not recognized
```

Curiously, if I run `DESCRIBE RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();` on the working ones, the type of the column gets reported as `TIMESTAMP_TZ(9)`. So it's doesn't seem (to me at least) like a type issue. Interestingly, if you manually cast the "bad" one to `TEXT`, it works.

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(MAX('2021-03-23 14:30:56.541 +0000'::TIMESTAMP)::TEXT, '');   -- Works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the second value in the COALESCE is TEXT and the first is TIMESTAMP and they do not implicitly auto convert.

```
SELECT 
    MAX('2021-03-23 14:30:56.541 +0000'::TIMESTAMP) as a
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(a) as type_a
    ,'' as b 
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(b) as type_b
    --,COALESCE(a, b)
    ;
```

| A | TYPE_A | B | TYPE_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-23 14:30:56.541 | TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)[SB16] |  | VARCHAR(1)[LOB] |

Now if you use a TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP if will not explode on the failed covert of an empty string into TIMESTAMP, but will give you NULL, which COALESCE will accept as the types are now the same, but in reality, that is as useless as COALESCE is trying to replace NULL..

```
SELECT 
    MAX('2021-03-23 14:30:56.541 +0000'::TIMESTAMP) as a
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(a) as type_a
    ,'' as b 
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(b) as type_b
    ,try_to_timestamp(b) as try_b
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(try_b) as type_try_b
    ,COALESCE(a, try_b) as col_res
    ;
```

| A | TYPE_A | B | TYPE_B | TRY_B | TYPE_TRY_B | COL_RES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-23 14:30:56.541 | TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)[SB16] |  | VARCHAR(1)[LOB] |  | TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)[SB16] | 2021-03-23 14:30:56.541 |

So then the question becomes, what are you really trying to get as the output by COALESCE'ing the first value?

"Your 'It works when I make the timestamp a string'" is because now both are strings, so their types match. Which if you are wanting to avoid null results, and want a empty string, then converting to string makes sense as a thing to do.

Comment: I understand this, in principle and in practice, but what I don't understand is why does adding MAX change things? In your first query, if you remove the MAX, the types are exactly the same, yet the COALESCE will succeed. If you add the MAX, the types don't change, yet it fails.

Comment: agreed the last column is "too much" `SELECT 
    '2021-03-23 14:30:56.541 +0000' as s
    ,s::timestamp as t
    ,max(t) as max_t
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(s)
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(t)
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(max_t)
    ,'' as b 
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(b) as type_b
    ,COALESCE(s, b) as col_s_b
    ,COALESCE(t, b) as col_t_b
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(col_t_b) as type_col_t_b
    /*,COALESCE(max_t, b) as col_t_b*/
    ;`  so why? I assume it's related to type implicit conversion. Perhaps it is a bug, that should be reported.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because of the effort and detail. However, as your comment indicated, there's something still going on. This is not the first time I've caught Snowflake doing things that are inconsistent no matter how you slice them.